# PDOException “could not find driver”

Tags: php, sql-server, driver

I'm on IIS, with PHP Version 5.2.17 on mssql database.

My database connection :

```
<?php

    include('myPDO.class.php');

    myPDO::setConfiguration('dblib:host=ebase\eb105;dbname=projettest2;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
```

Here is my error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in E:\www\ndatest\MetierSiteClient\myPDO.class.php:51

In my php.ini, I got :

```
[PHP_PDO]
extension=php_pdo.dll
[PHP_PDO_MSSQL]
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
```

And in my php.info, it is displayed :

```
PDO Driver for MSSQL DB-lib  //   enabled
Flavour                      //   MSSQL_70
```

and

```
PDO support // enabled
PDO drivers // firebird, mssql, mysql, odbc, sqlite2
```

So, do you have any ideas about it ? :(
Thanks!

Comment: `dblib`? Shouldn't that be `mssql:...`?

Comment: ok, i'm retarded, used to program on mysql and on local, i'm so lost in this company :<, thanks!

Comment: well, unless that DSN you're passing to your db lib is mangled by your pdo wrapper, presumably that's a PDO dsn, and you're telling it you've got a database whose driver is `dblib`. That's like going to a garage and saying your car's name is Fred and do they have parts for it, without ever mentioning what brand/model it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this code:

```
$banco = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_do_banco', 'username','password')or die(mysql_error());
```

after connected, if you want to connect using *charset*, use the code bellow:

```
<?php  
define('HOST', 'localhost');  
define('DBNAME', 'DB_BLOG');  
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');  
define('USER', 'root');  
define('PASSWORD', '123456');

try {  
  $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');  
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . HOST . "; dbname=" . DBNAME . "; charset=" . CHARSET . ";", USER, PASSWORD, $opcoes);  
  /*$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);*/
} catch (PDOException $e) {  
  echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();  
}  
var_dump($pdo);
```